# using IPv6 addresses in proxy.pac

Tags: proxy, ipv6, pac

When creating PAC files, one can use functions like isInNet, for example
if (isInNet(host, "10.9.9.9", "255.0.255.0"))
 return "DIRECT";
However, it doesn't make sense to use IP and wildcard/mask when using
IPv6 address.

My question is, what is the standard for PAC files when using IP addresses?
Do PAC files even support IPv6 addresses? Where can I verify?

Thanks

Comment: Why do IPv6 netmasks not make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

Various blog articles have reduced to using `shExpMatch`:

http://it.knightnet.org.uk/2009/02/proxypac-files-mozilla-firefox.html

http://desrablog.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-pac-to-auto-config-ipv6-proxy.html

On Windows stack native support for IPv6 inside Inet & WinHTTP libraries appears with Vista:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/07/18/ipv6-wpad-for-winhttp-and-wininet.aspx

An interesting bug in the Chromium project discussing IPv6 handling between browsers:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24641

> For MSIE compatibility the following
>   APIs only function with IPv4
>   addresses:
>
> `myIpAddress()`
>     `dnsResolve()`
>     `isResolvable()`