# What is Host "[::]:443" in proxy request?

Tags: proxy, https, http

I have a Firefox configured to use my proxy server.  The proxy is receiving a request from Firefox with the header:

```
CONNECT [::]:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: [::]:443
```

What is the meaning of this?  It can't connect to any 3rd party host, so what is the proxy meant to do?

(I've tried a few google searches but the syntax confuses Google...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[::]` is the shorthand IPv6 notation of localhost.

`:443` is HTTPS.

Your browser is making a request to `https://localhost` over IPv6.

Usually clients are configured not to use proxies for local connections. It seems like you have a client where this option has been turned off.

Comment: Ok but the proxy is configured via IPv4 on a cloud server.  Why would firefox make a request to localhost, and send it to a remote proxy?

Comment: Do you know what I can write in the PAC file so it doesn't forward the localhost requests?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with proxy.pac, but is this helpful? https://serverfault.com/questions/267280/using-ipv6-addresses-in-proxy-pac

Comment: I just wrote "if (isPlainHostName(host)) return 'DIRECT';" and it seems to work OK.  Thanks for your help.